# Js, How to ignore symbols that contribute text length in textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to count text that are not symbols in textbox. For example, if user type in `email_ex_3/2@mail.com` the original length of the text is 21 but my goal is to ignore these symbols so the length become 16.

All I can think is using for loops to check these symbols, but I think it is very hideous.

**JS**

```
function test() {
    alert(document.getElementById("firstText").value.length);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="firstText" />
<button onclick="test()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: So do you want to count the alphanumerical chars ?

Comment: only words and numbers

Comment: So you’d put `.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, "")` right before `.length`.

Comment: Oh my, this works perfectly! Is there any documentation regarding this characters `/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g` that u mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `replace` method by passing a *regular expression* as the second argument.

```js
function test(){
    alert(document.getElementById("firstText").value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, "").length);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="firstText"/>
<button onclick="test()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: this answer also works, is there any documentation regarding this characters `/[^a-z0-9]/gi` that u mentioned

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression to `replace` all non-word characters with the empty string, and check the `length` of the result:

```js
const getLen = str => str.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '').length;
console.log(getLen('email_ex_3/2@mail.com'));
```

Comment: this works also, but i'm looking for a simpler version

Comment: @learnprogramming, the simples version is to use `replace` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
function test()
{

alert(document.getElementById("firstText").value.replace(/[\W_]+/g, "").length);
}
```

(/[\W_]) exclude all non-alphanumeric characters and /g for saying all